# How to show exact error instead of ASP.NET Web API return UnknowError(500)

Tags: asp.net, exception, asp.net-web-api2, http-status-code-404

When the Company not found with its company ID, I would like to return the 404 status code. But Web API always returns;

```
  "error": {
    "message": "An error has occurred. Please, try it later.",
    "issuedAt": "2020-08-18T08:06:19.4650733Z",
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "statusCode": 500
  }
}
```

This is my CustomerProvider code;

```
public class CustomerProvider: ICustomerProvider
    {
        public CustomerProvider GetCustomerDetails()
        {
            //.....
            //.....
            
                if (customerDetails == null)
                {
                    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                    {
                        Content = new StringContent(string.Format("No customer with ID = {0}", customerId)),
                        ReasonPhrase = "Company ID Not Found"
                    };
                    throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
                }
            
                return customerDetails;
        }
    }
```

How can I return 404 status code?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
HttpResponseMessage err_response = (HttpResponseMessage)Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Your Message");
return err_response;
```

I wouldn't suggest that because it is not (404) it is a "Server Error (500)"